# MySQL UNION and like multiple table . #1064 Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union, sql-like

Thanks for reading my question.
I am trying to connect the 3 columns of multiple tables together then find the nameProduct column that match LIKE request.
All tables have different columns and look just like 3 columns: name, id and rate.
This is my code:

```
(
    SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
    FROM
        tblaptoplist 

)
UNION
    (
    SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
    FROM
        tbcpulist 
)
UNION
    (
    SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
    FROM
        tbgraphicslist
)
UNION
    (
    SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
    FROM
        tbpccaselist 
)
UNION
    (
    SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
    FROM
        tbradiatorslist 
)
UNION
    (
    SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
    FROM
        tbramlist 

)WHERE nameProduct LIKE 'Asus'
;
```

And MySQL was report:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
    nameProduct LIKE 'Asus' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 54
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Reconsider whether you should really have multiple tables for a single concept (product name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply `WHERE` to the result of `UNION` directly. You can filter queries for each subselect or wrap result of UNION in SELECT:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
      (
      SELECT
        nameProduct,
        rate,
        idProduct
      FROM
        tblaptoplist 
      )
      UNION ...
  ) AS r
 WHERE r.nameProduct LIKE 'Asus'
```

Comment: Thank you. MySQL no longer reported error # 1064. Can you help me with this one more question, 'Why is no data queried even if I am sure there is data matching the request'.